# Reply email based on senders email domain

Tags: javascript, email

So i have written two scripts that i call after each other, as a response to a user filling in a form.

"GetEditResonseUrls" Insert and edit_url into my spreadsheet.

"ReplyEmail2" Send an reply email to user, with HTML body, and two attached files as pdf.

What i would like is to add another e-mail reply, based on the domain of the e-mail of the user, and in this reply insert the EditUrl link.
     If @domail1.com, @domain2.com etc. then send "ReplyEmail1", otherwise send "ReplyEmail2".

Another way os saying it, i will not allow users to use certain domains, therefore i will send an emailreply1 through which they can change their email address in the form. Thereafter they will then get the emailreply2 sent to them which includes specific files.

I know how to add two e-mail replies, and to call the correct data from the spreadsheet, however i do not know how to write the "if" / "else" condition script - anyone can help?

```
function expCalc(){
  getEditResponseUrls();
  ReplyEmail2();
}


var formID = 'FormID'; 
var sheetName = 'Form Responses';
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openById (formID);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}


var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();
var file1 = DriveApp.getFileById('File id1');
var file2 = DriveApp.getFileById('File id2');

function ReplyEmail2() {
 MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "My email adress",
    subject: "subject",
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    attachments: [file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF), file2.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] 
  });
 }
```